# How to specify custom form validation error messages in symfony 2.5?

Tags: validation, symfony

I need to return custom error messages from form validation instead of Symfony's default 'This values is not valid'. I tried a few things on the validation.yml file with properties but could not accomplish this. Has anyone successfully done this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Constraints usually have the `message` option. You would use it like this:

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        firstName:
            - NotNull:
                message: Whatever!
```

**Update**

In the case of a `choice` constraint, there's more than one `message` option ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html)).

For example, if the `multiple` option is set to `true` you would use `multipleMessage`:

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        styles:
            - Choice: { choices: [novel, haiku], multiple: true, multipleMessage: Whatever! }
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it did not work for whatever reason. The validation just ignored it. I was trying to do it for a 'choice' type. I had to add it in the form itself using the 'invalid_message' attribute.

Comment: The `Valid` constraint unfortunately does not have the `message` option.